# QRegExp just not matching! Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Tags: c++, regex, qt, pattern-matching, qregexp

I am currently working on a Qt C++ application on Mac.
Throughout the application I am using string pattern matching pretty frequently.
When using the QRegExp class, I keep having trouble with something that I just don't understand!!!

My QRegExp looks like this :

```
QRegExp regEx("M|F\\dS\\d\\d.C\\d\\d", Qt::CaseInsensitive);
```

It is supposed to match patterns like "M1S02.C12" or "F4S14.C01" in filenames.
This works great as soon as the input filenames, which should be matched don't contain parts of this pattern.

For example : 
my input file is named "testItem_abcd_M1S03.C02_grade3"

```
regEx.exactMatch("testItem_abcd_M1S03.C02_grade3");
```

returns false, whereas

```
regEx.indexIn("testItem_abcd_M1S03.C02_grade3");
```

returns 7, which is the position of "m" in "item".

Can someone please tell me, what I would need to do to make it match right?

Thanks in advance,
guitarflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `|` restricts to searching either `M` or `F\dS\d\d.C\d\d`. So the sinle m of item will match.

Try `"[MF]\\dS\\d\\d\\.C\\d\\d"` instead.
(Note: Also replaced `.` with `\\.`, as a single dot matches any character)

Comment: `[MF]...` is the correct way to write this character class. Otherwise, a literal `|` will also match in this position.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Didn't think of that... Updated the statement

Comment: @guitarflow: Now you have enough reputation to upvote (click the upwards pointing triangle) and accept (click the checkmark) this question :)

Comment: No, not yet ... got 14, need 15 :) Will vote as soon as I am allowed to